# How to extract specific text from a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

In this case, I want to extract the beginning text in a cell and leave the remainder intact.
e.g. a series of cells contain:

```
2nd Unit. Miami
3rd Production Staff. Toronto
1st Ad. San Francisco
```

I want to break this up without using Text to columns as previous rows are formatted differently and these last few rows are outliers that I want to handle.

I thought Regular Expressions might do it, but that seems a bit complex.

My algorithm idea is:
1. grab the wanted text (what function or custom sub would do that?)
2. Past the text to it's new location
3. Cut the text from the cell, leaving the remaining text.

Seems simple but I'm still wending my way through VBA forest, and at the rate I'm going it's going to end up faster doing it by hand. But this seems like a good opportunity to learn some VBA tricks.

TIA

Update:
I want to take the text up to the ".\ " and move it to a different column, keeping the remainder where it is.

Comment: What do you mean by `the beginning text`? the first character? the first word (up to a space)? up to the first `.`? or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to want to modify the cell text in place, VBA will be required.

Inside a loop that sets `cl` to the cell to be processed:

```
str = cl.value
i = Instr(str, ".\")
cl = Trim(Mid$(str, i + 2))  ' assuming you want to exclude the ".\"
cl.Offset(0, 1) Trim(Left$(str, i - 1)) ' Places the original first part one cell to the right
```

Answer (score 3):

VBA is unnecessary. To get the text after .\ in cell A1: `=MID(A1,FIND(".\",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))` to get the text before .\ in A1: `=LEFT(A1,FIND(".\",A1,1)-1)`.

As additional information, `Find` returns the placement in the string where `.\` appears. It is the equivalent of `InStr` in VBA. If `.\` is not in the cell, it will display `#VALUE`, because I didn't bother to add error checking.

Comment: I want the text up to and including .[space], extract it and leave the remainder, thus I DO need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone who had this same question, here is the fully tested, working code.

```
Function RE6(strData As String) As String
  Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object

  Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  With RE
      .MultiLine = False
      .Global = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]B"
      RE6 = .test(strData)
  End With

  Set REMatches = RE.Execute(strData)
  If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
      RE6 = True
  Else
      RE6 = False
  End If
End Function

Sub territory()
Dim strTest As String, str As String, cl As Range
  strTest = ActiveCell.Value
  Set cl = ActiveCell
  If RE6(strTest) = True Then
      str = cl.Value
      i = InStr(str, ". ")
      cl = Trim(Mid$(str, i + 2))
      cl.Offset(0, 1) = Trim(Left(str, i - 1))
      cl.Offset(0, 2) = "Instance"
      MsgBox RE6(strTest)
  End If
End Sub
```